# SQLite error - no such function: InitSpatialMetadata

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, spatialite, sqlite

I am porting a QGIS plugin to QGIS3.

I get a problem when I try to create a new SpatiaLite DB, in particular when I initialize spatial metadata (`GEOMETRY_COLUMNS` and `SPATIAL_REF_SYS`).

My code is:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
con.enable_load_extension(True)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
cur.execute("SELECT InitSpatialMetaData(1);")
```

I get the following error :

> "no such function: InitSpatialMetadata"

My SQLite version is 3.29.0.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 5):

You won't make a error if you load the extension `mod_spatialite`. Look at the following code :

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
con.enable_load_extension(True)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
con.execute("SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')") -- add this line 
cur.execute("SELECT InitSpatialMetaData(1);")
```